# How to run Boost.Asio server on port 80?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a simple `boost.asio` server which I am trying to run it on port `80`. I am running the code inside a `try-catch` and I get a "`bind`" exception error. The value of `boost::error_code` is 13 which I think is "access denied".

I am running the code from `Xcode` on `Mac` running `Yosemite`. I also tried to run `Xcode` with sudo.

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run as root.

The problem is that you don't have the permission to bind to a privileged port (<1024 on most systems).

If you're certain that the child process of Xcode runs as root, find out which process is already listening on port 80 (`lsof` and `netstat`)

Comment: I tried this with: sudo open "path to Xcode", with no effect